# Using array values in images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, append

I have a some pictures with values of 1 - 10 E.G. img1.png, img2.png etc.

I also have some code that returns a number. What I would like is to have the returned number append an image.
My code is below and I can't get it to work properly. without the image it returns a normal number, but with it I get a blank return.

```
$("#ext-row").append("<div class='container returnedInfo'><div class='col-md-2 wordValue'> <img src'/Content/Images/img'" + items[i].WordScore + ".png</div>
```

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: What does the `items` array look like? Also note that your `img` element is missing a closing `/>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Looks like the img src is also missing `=`. Perhaps it should be: `<img src='/Content/Images/img'`

Comment: @redditor well spotted - I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your markup:

- no `=` next to src
- you are closing the src attribute value before appending the image
- you never closed the `img` tag

`<img src'/Content/Images/img'" + items[i].WordScore + ".png`

The proper code:

```
$("#ext-row").append("<div class='container returnedInfo'><div class='col-md-2 wordValue'> <img src='/Content/Images/img" + items[i].WordScore + ".png' /></div>");
```

Also make sure the image path you provide is valid.